# Display Image on nth iteration php

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am developing an app where I want to show 1 image at a time every 5th tweet, I have 18 images in total. Once all images display I want to reset to image 1. Tweets saving is done, but problem is displaying image, Suppose I have 122 tweets on DB.

```
<?php 
$total=0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select count(1) FROM tweets");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];
if (($total + 1) % 5 == 0) {
  echo '<img src='img/cities/1.jpg' />';
}
?>
```

I am stuck on this logic.

Comment: You're talking about iteration, but I see no looping logic anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code exaple shows an image if the row count is dividable by 5.
The image index will be calculated by dividing the row count by 5 so you know which 5th group is shown. Now we take mod 18 and add 1 so we get a range from 1-18

```
$rowCount = $row[0];
$imageIndex = floor($rowCount / 5) % 18 +1;
if(($rowCount % 5) == 0)
{
  echo '<img src="img/cities/'.$imageIndex.'.jpg" />';       
}
```

Comment: In this way, all image will be shown, How can I display one at a time?

Comment: In your question you said "1 image at a time every 5th tweet". I thought you want to display all the rows and show an image every 5th row, is that correct?

Comment: No, I mean One image only whatever the row count will be, Like if i have 5 tweets on DB then image1 will show then on 10th tweets image2 will show, image 1 should hide, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: I think you can do it this Php and jQuery. Hide in JS the ID image and show the next One.

Comment: @Portekoi no need to use JS. Can be done with every language.

Comment: Like I understand, he want to hide the previous image for show the next one. So, if it's web, you need javascript. But I misunderstood the question maybe.

Comment: @davidgiga1993,Now I have 100 tweets still showing 3th image only :(

Comment: @Roger But that's correct. 100 = 20 groups of 5. So it should show the 20th image, but you only got 18  -> so it's showing the 3rd.

Comment: 94 tweets now, no image is display @davidgiga1993. Crashed :(

Comment: Fixed. Forgot that PHP is always using floats when dividing. Added a round() call around the division.

Comment: Probelm with if statment, displaying 2 but not echo @davidgiga1993